# What is the letter combination?

Tags: middle-english, paleography

What is the Middle English letter combination?

In Mk.9:4 Studylight says it is "pp", but in Mt.21:26 it is not "pp".

[Wycliffe's Bible (page 76)](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/)

**Mk.9:4**

[Studylight:](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=Matthew%2021%3A26&search_form_type=general&q1=Mark%209%3A4&s=2&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)

"...and Helie with Moises apperide to hem, and thei spaken with Jhesu."

King James Bible:

"And there appeared unto them Elias with Moses: and they were talking with Jesus."

[Wycliffe's Bible (page 44)](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/)

**Mt.21:26**

[Studylight:](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=Mark%209%3A4&search_form_type=general&q1=Mt.21%3A26&s=2&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)

"...not to hym? If we seien of men, we dreden the puple, for alle hadden Joon as a prophete."

King James Bible:

"But if we shall say, Of men; we fear the people; for all hold John as a prophet."

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see how the second example is a double 'p' at all. It looks like 'a?phhete'. the '?' character is for some character I don't recognize, but it doesn't look like the adjacent 'p'.

Comment: @Anatoliy Sydorov: I wish your links would open in new tabs rather than taking us away from this page. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Ctrl+Click

Comment: @Mitch: the double p in apperide looks just like the symbol in "prophet". So it looks like it's "a pphhete", which might be a reasonable abbreviation of "prophet" if it didn't have an extra "h".

Comment: Thank you, Anatoliy. I learn something new every day. We should keep in mind that Wycliffe's New Testaments were *handwritten* not typeset, so what we are seeing in this "1400 version" is the work of a scribe tediously penned years after Wycliffe's death at the end of December, 1384. I agree that "A pphhete" or "A?phhete" doesn't make any sense out of context, but I would suggest it's just a quirk of the scribe and not a unique, established *letter combination*. (In contrast, see the word "pupplicans" further down that column, in which the pp's are not connected as they are in "apperide.")

Comment: (Corresponds to Matthew 21:32, "For Joon cam to you in the weie of riytwisnesse, and ye bileueden not to him; but pupplicans and hooris bileueden to hym." ibid)